# clickonce github commit setup.exe

Tags: c#, github, clickonce

Hello I used this https://developers.de/2018/02/10/clickonce-on-github/ tutorial to add my clickonce solution to github. It kinda worked like a sharm, the raw link was wrong for me but I got the right one  by clicking on my ".application" file and then "raw" and changed the link for updates and publishing in my solution properties according to the tutorial mentiont before.

well that beeing said now I entcounter a weired behaviour when I expect a update for my tool.

1. I change something in my tool
2. I publish it
3. I push it to github

Now I start my tool to check for updates and I would expect an Update to be installed but there is none  because the setup.exe was only updated localy and not in the git ripository. To start an update I have to manually delete the setup.exe from github first and then push it again.

Is this normal do I have to add something to my .gitignore or .gitattributes file?

Thanks for helping.